# Not understanding how Coalesce works?

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

I thought I understood how `coalesce` works in oracle, but for some reason this simple select statement isnt bring up what its supposed to. My understand of `coalesce` is that it goes through all the values in the parenthesis until it hits the value that is in the field it is looking at. In my code the two accounts in the select have a `rr.rel_type` of Customer2. I double checked this by looking at the values in `racctrel`. When I run the code though, zero results come up. Here is the code:

```
SELECT lt.ACCOUNT, 
       rr.rel_type,
       lt.transaction_date, 
       lt.amount, 
       lt.transaction_code, 
       ltc.fintran_tran_code, 
       fo.FIRM_NAME AS ATTORNEY, 
       lt.debtor_ssn, 
       REPLACE(rr.NAME,';',',') AS DEBTOR_NAME, 
       lt.description AS COST_DESCRIPTION,
       pd.owner
FROM legal_transactions lt, 
     legal_transaction_codes ltc, 
     firms_onboarded fo, 
     racctrel rr,
     package_details pd,
     raccount ra
WHERE fo.attorney_id = lt.attorney_id
AND rr.ACCOUNT = lt.ACCOUNT
AND ra.ACCOUNT = lt.ACCOUNT
and pd.package_id = ra.user_text_3
AND ltc.transaction_code = lt.transaction_code
AND lt.batch_id = 865
AND upper(rr.rel_type) = coalesce('CUSTOMER1','PRIMDEBTOR','CUSTOMER2')
AND lt.ACCOUNT IN ('17149146','17918854');
```

---

```
SELECT account, rel_type
FROM racctrel
where ACCOUNT IN ('17149146','17918854');
```

The results are:

```
17918854    Customer2
17149146    Customer2
```

Comment: coalesce returns the first non-null expression in the list.  Since you're passing strings, that would always be 'CUSTOMER1'

Comment: may be you should check what exactly `coalesce()` does. http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-coalesce.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it works as it should:

Here

```
AND upper(rr.rel_type) = coalesce('CUSTOMER1','PRIMDEBTOR','CUSTOMER2')
```

the result of `COALESCE` is `'CUSTOMER1'` - first not null value, and here

```
17918854    Customer2
17149146    Customer2
```

you have only `'CUSTOMER2'`.

So it's correct:

```
AND upper(rr.rel_type) = coalesce('CUSTOMER1','PRIMDEBTOR','CUSTOMER2')

=> 

AND 'CUSTOMER2' = 'CUSTOMER1'
```

is false.

Comment: Yeah I knew it stopped at the first non null, but I thought it worked differently. Essentially I thought that since rr.rel_type was null for `'CUSTOMER1'` and `'PRIMDEBTOR'` (since the accounts didnt have these values) it would stop at `'CUSTOMER2'`. Just a misunderstanding on my part, thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

`coalesce` returns the first not-null argument, or `NULL` if all arguments are `NULL`. So `coalesce('CUSTOMER1','PRIMDEBTOR','CUSTOMER2')` always evaluates to `'CUSTOMER1'`. What you might want here is an `IN` clause. Instead of

```
AND upper(rr.rel_type) = coalesce('CUSTOMER1','PRIMDEBTOR','CUSTOMER2')
```

write

```
AND upper(rr.rel_type) in ('CUSTOMER1','PRIMDEBTOR','CUSTOMER2')
```